# Securing the Custom Record list data

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am storing secure token values in the custom record i created. I wanted to secure those values by restricting access. 
So first solution i came up with is unchecking the  field "ALLOW UI ACCESS" while creating custom record and selecting "LOCK the custom record" while building the bundle using SuiteBundler->Create Bundle.

The problem with this approach is even though we can restrict users to view records created.But it cannot stop the scripts from accessing the values of that custom record.

In this case , can someone please tell how to secure that record list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to restrict access to a specific Role?  I think you can do that in the custom record settings.

Comment: Yes i did that . Thanks . I am looking for more secure solution like encrypting the data .